# Is there a way to emulate PHP5's __call() magic method in PHP4?

Tags: php4, delegation

PHP5 has a "magic method" `__call()`that can be defined on any class that is invoked when an undefined method is called -- it is roughly equivalent to Ruby's `method_missing` or Perl's `AUTOLOAD`. Is it possible to do something like this in older versions of PHP?

Comment: This article, [Using Method Call Overloading in PHP 4 ](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Using-Method-Call-Overloading-in-PHP-4/) over on DevShed might help.

Answer (score 2):

The most important bit that I was missing was that `__call` exists in PHP4, but you must enable it on a per-class basis by calling `overload()`, as seen in [php docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.overload.php) .
Unfortunately, the __call() function signatures are different between PHP4 and PHP5, and there does not seem to be a way to make an implementation that will run in both.

Answer (score 0):

I recall using it, and a little bit of googling suggests that

```
function __call($method_name, $parameters, &$return)
{
  $return_value = "You called ${method_name}!";
}
```

as a member function will do the job.

Comment: I suspect jes5199 was thinking of the __call method when he asked if anyone knew anything like the __call method... I think "in PHP4" was the critical part of the question.

Comment: Yes, and I was referring to PHP4. Note the change in signature, which changed in 5.

Comment: ah, it looks like you're right, but also (a vital bit that I was missing), you must use the overload("ClassName") function to *enable* the __call method.