# Declarative access to structured PHP variable without foreach loops

Tags: php, data-structures, variables

**Background**

Assume I have the following nested variable in PHP.

```
$data = Array(
Array('lname'  =>  'Simpson','fname'  =>  'Homer','age'    =>  '35','motto'  =>  '_blank_'),
Array('lname'  =>  'Simpson','fname'  =>  'Marge','age'    =>  '34','motto'  =>  '_blank_'),
Array('lname'  =>  'Flintstone','fname'  =>  'Fred','age'    =>  '33','motto'  =>  '_blank_'),
Array('lname'  =>  'Flintstone','fname'  =>  'Wilma','age'    =>  '29','motto'  =>  '_blank_')
);
```

Assume also the standard methods for accessing specific values:

```
print($data[0]['fname']);  // Homer
print($data[1]['age']);    // 34
```

**Question**

Is there an existing library or framework that would allow me to easily
acess specific values declaratively, without using foreach loops?

```
$test = $data->get_record_by_fname['Homer']
print $test['age'] //35
```

Comment: If not, you can always make your own!

Comment: Any function that would exist like that would use a foreach loop anyways, you're far better off writing your own framework using a foreach loop than searching the internet for something that isn't there.

Comment: I've already done it myself and I am not the only person who has had this idea. The question is to see how other people have done it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really wanted to overkill everything, you could try an approach using magical methods!

```
class Simpsons
{
    protected $_data = array();

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->_data = array_map(function ($i) { return (object)$i; }, $data);
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (count($args) == 0)
            return NULL;

        foreach ($this->_data as $row)
        {
            if (property_exists($row, $method) && $row->$method == $args[0])
            {
                return $row;
            }
        }

        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$p = new Simpsons($data); // Stored in the format provided

var_dump($p->fname('Homer')); // Gets the record with fname = Homer
```

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76328/is-there-a-way-to-emulate-php5s-call-magic-method-in-php4

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you don't want to use foreach loops? If it's merely for conciseness, you could just declare the function yourself, it's fairly trivial:

```
function get_record($set, $field, $value) {
    foreach($set as $key => $val) {
        if($val[$field] === $value) return $set[$key];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Then your example would become:

```
$test = get_record($data, 'fname', 'Homer');
print $test['age']; //35
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeClass{

    // Stores the Array of Data
    public $data;

    // Sets up the object. Only accepts arrays
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    // Gets a record based on the key/value pair
    public function getByKey($key, $value)
    {
        foreach($this->data as $array)
        {
                if(is_array($array)
                {
                    if(array_key_exists($key, $array) && $array[$key] == $value)
                    {
                        return $array;
                    }
                 }
        }
    }

}

$array = array( 1 => array("Test" => "Hello"));
$obj = new SomeClass($array);

$record = $obj->getByKey('Test', 'Hello');
```

This lets you get a record based on what a key/value pair inside the array is. Note, the type hinting in the constructor is PHP 5.3(?)

BTW, No, there is no way to escape the `foreach` as even internal PHP functions (anything beginning with `array_`) uses a `foreach` or some other type of loop. However, if you encapsulate the loop into a class, you don't have to think about it.